# How would you go about integrating this?

Tags: integration

$$ \int \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{4x}\,}\,\mathrm{d}x $$

I've tried using u-substitution but can't seem to get everything in terms of u. I was wondering if anyone can help point me in the right direction or let me know if I can use another method.

Comment: I tried updating your use of latex, please respond if this is not the integral you are seeking to solve.

Comment: This is it. I struggled trying to get it into that form, so I hoped what I wrote down was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting $$t=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}}$$ then we have $$x=\frac{1}{4(t^2-1)}$$ and $$dx=\frac{1}{4}(-1)(t^2-1)^{-2}2tdt$$
can you finish?
a possible solution is this here $$\frac{1}{8} \left(4 \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+4} x+\log \left(4
   \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+4}+2\right) x+1\right)\right)$$

Comment: Yes, I can. Thank you. I was using u = 1+1/(4x) rather than including the square root sign along with it.

Comment: substitute the square root, this will help

Comment: Why is this down voted? This is a good way to solve the problem.